# GameActivity template fails cmake build

Tags: cmake, android-gameactivity

Cmake fails using the GameActivity template.

#### To recreate the problem:

1. Use the GameActivity template from Android Developer to create a new project.

How do I get GameActivity working?

#### I tried:

`[CXX1405] exception while building Cmake using [local file path]/CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [configure] failed when executing: [local file path]/cmake.exe`

[CXX1405 cmake exception while building android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825520/cxx1405-cmake-exception-while-building-android-project)

[CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project after updating Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803445/cmake-will-not-be-able-to-correctly-generate-this-project-after-updating-android)

I tried navigating the Google Developers website for a solution. There was no step by step solution on Android Developer docs.

tried to adjust build dependencies.

Comment: "encountered the same cmake error" - Add the error message into your **question post**. On Stack Overflow a question post is expected to fully contain a problem statement. You may refer to other resources (and questions) for additional data, but main information should be in your question post.

Comment: Please, post **complete** error message, not just the first words of it. E.g. the [question answered by yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71803445/3440745) provides much more text.

Comment: Please note, that Stack Overflow is NOT a *discussion* forum like Google groups. It is a library of **question posts** and their **answers**. Every question should contain all relevant information about the problem, and the error message is the main part of that information. I agree that when someone asks a question, they could be not aware whether logs are relevant to the problem. But why do not **copy paste** the error message when **initially** ask a question?

Comment: Is the part of the error message `C++ build system [configure] failed when executing` **exact**? Google finds many messages with "while" instead "when", e.g. [here](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/issues/333#issuecomment-1278563308). If you wonder why it is important to provide the error message exactly, then you could look into that [answer on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359147/3440745).

Comment: There is a bug ticket to fix the template (will do it for sure). In the mean time, look at https://developer.android.com/games/agdk/game-activity; and 2 examples (https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/hello-vulkan, https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/pull/549). A simple one is here: https://github.com/ggfan/playground/blob/master/android/games/gamesdk/GameActivity/template/).

Comment: Please clearly and succinctly provide the exact steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The updated template should work better:

- 2022.2.1 Canary 2 (from https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/); or next version of Flamingo.
- [hello-vulkan sample](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/hello-vulkan) and [Khronos Vulkan sample repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/pull/549) should also work

If you are using NativeActivity, switching to GameActivity might [reduce ANR in certain scenarios](https://developer.android.com/stories/games/cat-daddy-agdk), hence GameActivity is in:

- [Unity GameEngine 2023.1+](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/Manual/android-application-entries-game-activity.html)
- [Next source release of Cobalt library](https://github.com/youtube/cobalt) used by YouTube app on Android TV platform (with hundreds of million users)

For new applications, starting with [GameActivity 2.0.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/games) might be good.